# Selecting radio button of GeoServer layer causes popup of different GeoServer layer to open instead

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms, popup

In continuation to [How to fetch the URL of specific GeoServer layer by switching radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856601/how-to-fetch-the-url-of-specific-geoserver-layer-by-switching-radio-button), I have tried to generate the URL of specific GeoServer layer after selecting the radio button of that layer.

```
$('input[name="WeatherParameterLayerRadioButton"]').on('click', function() {
var radioValue = $('input[name="WeatherParameterLayerRadioButton"]:checked').val();
```

for which, I have created an array of Layers

```
let district_url_pass = [
  rainfall_layer, 
  maximum_temperature_layer, 
  minimum_temperature_layer,
  cloud_cover_layer]
```

While Checking the radio button, the URL of Button, which I am Checking, is getting generated at last, but still, the URL's of other parameters are being generated, which are appearing as the Popup
[image]

```
    $('input[name="WeatherParameterLayerRadioButton"]').on('click', function() {
        var radioValue = $('input[name="WeatherParameterLayerRadioButton"]:checked').val(); 



        let district_url_pass = [
            india_dist_rainfall_layer, 
            india_dist_maximum_temperature_layer, 
            india_dist_minimum_temperature_layer,
            india_dist_cloud_cover_layer]


        map.on('click',function(evt){
        var resolution=map.getView().getResolution();
        var coordinate=evt.coordinate;  
        var projection=map.getView().getProjection();
            
        switch(radioValue) {
            case 'Rainfall_layer':
              processRainfallClick();
              break;
            case 'Maximum_temperature_layer':
              processMaxTemperatureClick();
              break;
            case 'Minimum_temperature_layer':
              processMinTemperatureClick();
              break;
            default:
              processCloudCoverClick();
            console.log(radioValue);
          }

        function processRainfallClick() {
            var Rainfall_layer_url=district_url_pass[0].getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
            coordinate,
            resolution,
            projection,
            {
            'INFO_FORMAT':'application/json',
            'FEATURE_COUNT': '5', 
            'propertyName': 'issue_date,forecast_date,district_name,rainfall'
            })
            console.log("URL Fired at processRainfallClick():", Rainfall_layer_url)
            $.getJSON(Rainfall_layer_url,function(Rainfall_data){
              popup_content.innerHTML = 
              '<table id="weather_forecast_table"> <caption> The forecast Issued on:&nbsp;' + Rainfall_data.features[0].properties.issue_date + ',' + '&nbsp; \nfor next 5 days of district:\n&nbsp;'+ Rainfall_data.features[0].properties.district_name+ '&nbsp; </caption> <tr><th>&nbsp; Forecast Date&nbsp; </th> <th> &nbsp; Rainfall (mm) &nbsp; </th>  <tr> <td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[0].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td> <td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[0].properties.rainfall + '&nbsp; </td></tr> <tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[1].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[1].properties.rainfall + '&nbsp; </td> <tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[2].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[2].properties.rainfall + '&nbsp; </td> <tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[3].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[3].properties.rainfall + '&nbsp; </td><tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[4].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[4].properties.rainfall + '&nbsp; </td> </tr></table>'
    
              overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
            })
        }

        function processMaxTemperatureClick() {
            var Maximum_temperature_url = district_url_pass[1].getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
                coordinate,
                resolution,
                projection,
                {
                'INFO_FORMAT':'application/json',
                'FEATURE_COUNT': '5', 
                'propertyName': 'issue_date,forecast_date,district_name,temperature_max'
                })
                console.log("URL Fired at processMaxTemperatureClick():"+Maximum_temperature_url)
                    $.getJSON(Maximum_temperature_url,function(Maximum_temperature_data){
                        popup_content.innerHTML = 
                        '<table id="weather_forecast_table"> <caption> The forecast Issued on:&nbsp;' + Maximum_temperature_data.features[0].properties.issue_date + ',' + '&nbsp; \nfor next 5 days of district:\n&nbsp;'+ Maximum_temperature_data.features[0].properties.district_name+ '&nbsp; </caption> <tr><th>&nbsp; Forecast Date&nbsp; </th> <th> &nbsp; Maximum Temperature  (°C) &nbsp; </th>  <tr> <td>&nbsp; ' + Maximum_temperature_data.features[0].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td> <td>&nbsp; ' + Maximum_temperature_data.features[0].properties.temperature_max + '&nbsp; </td></tr> <tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Maximum_temperature_data.features[1].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Maximum_temperature_data.features[1].properties.temperature_max + '&nbsp; </td> <tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Maximum_temperature_data.features[2].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Maximum_temperature_data.features[2].properties.temperature_max + '&nbsp; </td> <tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Maximum_temperature_data.features[3].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Maximum_temperature_data.features[3].properties.temperature_max + '&nbsp; </td><tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Maximum_temperature_data.features[4].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Maximum_temperature_data.features[4].properties.temperature_max + '&nbsp; </td> </tr></table>'
        
                        overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
                    })
            }

            function processMinTemperatureClick() {
            var Minimum_temperature_url = district_url_pass[2].getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
                coordinate,
                resolution,
                projection,
                {
                'INFO_FORMAT':'application/json',
                'FEATURE_COUNT': '5', 
                'propertyName': 'issue_date,forecast_date,district_name,temperature_min'
                })
                console.log("URL Fired at processMinTemperatureClick():"+Minimum_temperature_url)
                    $.getJSON(Minimum_temperature_url,function(Minimum_temperature_data){
                        popup_content.innerHTML = 
                        '<table id="weather_forecast_table"> <caption> The forecast Issued on:&nbsp;' + Minimum_temperature_data.features[0].properties.issue_date + ',' + '&nbsp; \nfor next 5 days of district:\n&nbsp;'+ Minimum_temperature_data.features[0].properties.district_name+ '&nbsp; </caption> <tr><th>&nbsp; Forecast Date&nbsp; </th> <th> &nbsp; Minimum Temperature  (°C) &nbsp; </th>  <tr> <td>&nbsp; ' + Minimum_temperature_data.features[0].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td> <td>&nbsp; ' + Minimum_temperature_data.features[0].properties.temperature_min + '&nbsp; </td></tr> <tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Minimum_temperature_data.features[1].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Minimum_temperature_data.features[1].properties.temperature_min + '&nbsp; </td> <tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Minimum_temperature_data.features[2].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Minimum_temperature_data.features[2].properties.temperature_min + '&nbsp; </td> <tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Minimum_temperature_data.features[3].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Minimum_temperature_data.features[3].properties.temperature_min + '&nbsp; </td><tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Minimum_temperature_data.features[4].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Minimum_temperature_data.features[4].properties.temperature_min + '&nbsp; </td> </tr></table>'

                        overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
                    })
            }

        function processCloudCoverClick() {
            var Cloud_cover_url=district_url_pass[7].getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
                coordinate,
                resolution,
                projection,
                {
                'INFO_FORMAT':'application/json',
                'FEATURE_COUNT': '5', 
                'propertyName': 'issue_date,forecast_date,district_name,cloud_cover',
                })
                console.log("URL Fired at processCloudCoverClick():", Cloud_cover_url)
                $.getJSON(Cloud_cover_url,function(Cloud_cover_data){
                    popup_content.innerHTML = 
                    '<table id="weather_forecast_table"> <caption> The forecast Issued on:&nbsp;' + Cloud_cover_data.features[0].properties.issue_date + ',' + '&nbsp; \nfor next 5 days of district:\n&nbsp;'+ Cloud_cover_data.features[0].properties.district_name+ '&nbsp; </caption> <tr><th>&nbsp; Forecast Date&nbsp; </th> <th> &nbsp; Cloud Cover (Octa) &nbsp; </th>  <tr> <td>&nbsp; ' + Cloud_cover_data.features[0].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td> <td>&nbsp; ' + Cloud_cover_data.features[0].properties.cloud_cover + '&nbsp; </td></tr> <tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Cloud_cover_data.features[1].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Cloud_cover_data.features[1].properties.cloud_cover + '&nbsp; </td> <tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Cloud_cover_data.features[2].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Cloud_cover_data.features[2].properties.cloud_cover + '&nbsp; </td> <tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Cloud_cover_data.features[3].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Cloud_cover_data.features[3].properties.cloud_cover + '&nbsp; </td><tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Cloud_cover_data.features[4].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Cloud_cover_data.features[4].properties.cloud_cover + '&nbsp; </td> </tr></table>'

                    overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
                })              
            }  
            });
    });
```

How to rectify this so that only that pop-up appears, which is selected using radio Button?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in the way you are handling radio button selection. On each selection you define new map `click` event function with `map.on('click', ...`, but the previous ones stay valid. As a consequence upon each click all those functions get fired.

Solution is to define map `click` event processing function only once and then within it decide which layer will be processes, depending on `radioValue`.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var resolution, coordinate, projection;

map.on('click', function (evt) {
  resolution = map.getView().getResolution();
  coordinate = evt.coordinate;
  projection = map.getView().getProjection();
  switch(radioValue) {
    case 'Rainfall_layer':
      processRainfallClick();
      break;
    case 'Maximum_temperature_layer':
      processMaxTemperatureClick();
      break;
    case 'Minimum_temperature_layer':
      processMinTemperatureClick();
      break;
    default:
      processCloudCoverClick();
  }
});
      
function processRainfallClick() {
  Rainfall_layer_url_pass = district_url_pass[0];
  var Rainfall_layer_url = Rainfall_layer_url_pass.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
    coordinate,
    resolution,
    projection, {
      'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
      'FEATURE_COUNT': '5',
      'propertyName': 'issue_date,forecast_date,district_name,rainfall'
    })
  console.log("Rainfall_layer_url:" + Rainfall_layer_url)
  if (Rainfall_layer_url) {
    $.getJSON(Rainfall_layer_url, function (Rainfall_data) {

      popup_content.innerHTML =
        '<table id="weather_forecast_table"> <caption> The forecast Issued on:&nbsp;' + Rainfall_data.features[0].properties.issue_date + ',' + '&nbsp; \nfor next 5 days of district:\n&nbsp;' + Rainfall_data.features[0].properties.district_name + '&nbsp; </caption> <tr><th>&nbsp; Forecast Date&nbsp; </th> <th> &nbsp; Rainfall (mm) &nbsp; </th>  <tr> <td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[0].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td> <td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[0].properties.rainfall + '&nbsp; </td></tr> <tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[1].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[1].properties.rainfall + '&nbsp; </td> <tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[2].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[2].properties.rainfall + '&nbsp; </td> <tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[3].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[3].properties.rainfall + '&nbsp; </td><tr><td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[4].properties.forecast_date + '&nbsp; </td><td>&nbsp; ' + Rainfall_data.features[4].properties.rainfall + '&nbsp; </td> </tr></table>'

      overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
    })
  }
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: Hiii, @TomazicM, Thanks for your time, I have followed your approach, but still, multiple URL's are being generated. I have cleared the console, and checked the cloud cover radio button, Its value is being shown at the last, but other URL's still building, while checking, as in console (the figure i have update in the Question above).

Comment: Is there any way to filter specific URL of only that parameter, which is assigned for a particular Radio Button when pressed, and other URL’s don't appear/generate . Maybe that way, The proper popup will show up.?

Comment: As far as I understand, this should work. Without possibility to try your actual code I can't say where it goes wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't try it since layers come from your local server.

Comment: Ohh Okay @TomazicM, any other way possible? (Remote Access or Anything)?

Comment: Sorry, no remote debugging. If problem is not Geoserver related but program logic related, you could replace your local resources with some public ones in your JS fiddle, of course reducing number of choices/radio buttons.

Comment: I got what the problem is, the window generates that many URL's as the number of time I hit the radio button, Like for the first time, if I hit the rainfall button, then 1 URL is generated, then if i hit the Temperature radio button 2 URL's are generated, if I hit the Cloud button then 3 URL,s are generated, and when i again hit the rainfall button then 4 URL's are generated. So i have to refresh the window, every time hit the radio button. window.location.reload(); is the function, but I am not sure where to put it to refresh the window, Can you please suggest if you know about it?